# Solutions for ODE with periodic B.C.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

I have the following ODE
$$-u(x)''=f(x) \qquad u:[0,1)$$
It is smooth and 1-periodic. Assume that I have a solution u(x). How do I prove that:
$$u(x)= u(x)+c \quad c \in \mathbb{R} $$
is also a solution. It is obvious by just looking at it. But how do I approach a proof?

Comment: The second derivative of $u(x) + c$ is the second derivative of $u(x)$.  What else do you need to say?

Comment: Would that be enough?

Comment: You show a function is a solution by plugging it in to the ODE and verifying that the left side and right side are equal (as functions). That's all there is to it.

Comment: If you have not just a differential equation but a boundary-value problem, you also have to check the boundary conditions.  But you didn't tell us any boundary conditions.